# how to set Content-Language while calling create inventory api on ebay?

Tags: httpclient, ebay-api

I am trying to add inventory on eBay with inventory api, it require Content-Language in request header, I am adding it in header but not accepting, could you please help with this. Thanks!

code is below:

```
                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
                     = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.AccessToken.Token);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Language", "en-US");
```

[Image shows that it is worked on rest client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWinn.png)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your [marketplace ID](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/rest-request-components.html#marketpl) also.  Please share the error so that the problem is more clear.

Comment: Content-Language header throws Misused header name error